# Creating a Parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

```
SELECT
Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM
sometable
```

Hi, I need help in creating a parameter in SSRS.

When False it should only display where `Field3 IS NOT NULL` and
When True it should display all records

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM sometable 
WHERE (@param = TRUE) OR (Field3 IS NOT NULL)
```